# React redux not updating on PrivateRoutes.js

Tags: react-redux, react-router-dom, create-react-app

Trying to implement PrivateRoutes.js using react-redux to update the isAuthenticated store. I think the problem is with when the render occurs but can't seem to get it to work.

PrivateRoutes.js

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { setIsAuthenticated, setAuthUser } from '../appSlice';


const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.app);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchAuthUser = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user", { withCredentials: true })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not properly authenticated");
        dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
        dispatch(setAuthUser(null));
  
      });

    if (response && response.data) {
      dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(true));
      dispatch(setAuthUser(response.data));
      console.log(response.data)
    }
  };

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchAuthUser();
      
    }, []);
  
  
    return(
      isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />
    )
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'
import Login from './Login';
import SecureArea from './SecureArea';
import PrivateRoutes from './utils/PrivateRoutes'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<Login/>} path="/login"/>
            <Route element={<Home/>} path="/" exact/>
            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                <Route element={<SecureArea/>} path="/SecureArea"/>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import appReducer from './appSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    app: appReducer,
  },
});

export { store };
```

appSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authUser: null,
};

const AppSlice = createSlice({
  name: "App",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsAuthenticated: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = action.payload;
    },
    setAuthUser: (state, action) => {
      state.authUser = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setIsAuthenticated, setAuthUser } = AppSlice.actions;
export default AppSlice.reducer;
```

Not sure why isAuthenticated remains as false. I don't think its my redux setup because I tried creating a button to change the isAuthenticated variable and that seems to work.